# Publish to Google Tasks from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

With iCal you can publish calendars for users to incorporate into their own calendars in Google Calendar.  Is there a similar way to publish tasks to be publicly visible and able to be incorporated into a task manager such as Google Tasks or Remember The Milk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favourite is the [Toodledo gem](http://github.com/wsargent/toodledo/tree/master), which integrates perfectly with Toodledo and includes a nice command line client.